# how to change the first word to yellow instead of white in powershell?

Tags: powershell

In powershell I have my sentences all blank I wanted to change the color of the first word to yellow just for appearance how can I do this?

I've tried using this command "Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ Command = 'Yellow' }" but it gives me this error "Set-PSReadLineOption : The term 'Set-PSReadLineOption' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if the path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again."

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: @jfrmilner 5.1.19041.1151

Comment: You need the PSReadLine module.

To install PSReadLine 2.1.0 in a supported version of PowerShell run the following command.

     Install-Module -Name PSReadLine -RequiredVersion 2.1.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: The latest version of the PSReadLine module still supports 5.1 so install that, it defaults to Yellow for CommandColor.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would set the first word to be coloured yellow and the rest of the line white:

```
Write-Host "YELLOW" -Foreground Yellow -NoNewLine
Write-Host " the rest of the line is white" -Foreground White
```

Which would output: `YELLOW the rest of the line is white`

Comment: I wanted the first word to always be in yellow I didn't want to print a word in yellow :|

Comment: Depending on how your code is, you can get it to always be yellow for the first word

Comment: i wanted to do this as powershell appearance setting

Comment: Expand your question, i dont understand what you mean by `powershell appearance setting`. Also, this is not a code writing service, the above code is one minimal way you can output text in a different colour - what you do with it is specific to your implementation. I would suggest writing your own function that uses the above technique, then you call your new function instead of Write-Host when you want to use your new coloured output (and in there would be your logic to split the string, and output the 1st word in yellow etc).